# search Value and delete cells in range

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

I have the following problem:

I search a value and want to delete the cell. But I need to delete the whole dataset (from Column A to E). E.g. I find a value in Cell B4 and want to delete the dataset A4 - E4. I don't want to delete the EntireRow because I have more data in the datasheet.

My Code:

```
Sub DeleteCells2()
 Dim rng As Range
 Dim i As Integer, counter As Integer, ib As String

ib = InputBox("Geben Sie bitte die PLZ und den Ort ein")
 'Set the range to evaluate to rng.
 Set rng = Range("C2:C99")

 'initialize i to 1
 i = 1

 'Loop for a count of 1 to the number of rows
 'in the range that you want to evaluate.
 For counter = 1 To rng.Rows.Count

      'If cell i in the range contains an "x",
       'delete the row.
       'Else increment i
        If rng.Cells(i) = ib Then
            rng.Cells(i).EntireRow.Delete
        Else
            i = i + 1
        End If

  Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want **deleting** that range or **clearing** it? Do you understand the difference? Why do you iterate using `count` and use `i` to compare/delete? Can you explain **in words** what you exactly try accomplishing?

Comment: I want to delete it. Im searching for a value in column C. Than i want to delete the dataset

Comment: `rng.Cells(i).EntireRow.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, 5).Delete`

Answer (score 1):

### Delete Data Rows

[image]

```
Sub DeleteLocation()
    
    Dim Location As String
    Location = InputBox("Geben Sie bitte die PLZ und den Ort ein")
    
    If Len(Location) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No location entered.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim crg As Range: Set crg = rg.Columns(3)
    
    Dim r As Long
    
    For r = crg.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
        If StrComp(CStr(crg.Cells(r).Value), Location, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            rg.Rows(r).Delete xlShiftUp
        'Else ' not a match; do nothing
        End If
    Next r
 
    MsgBox Location & " deleted.", vbInformation

End Sub
```